# move from imperative try-with-resource to reactive using, using()

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-webflux, project-reactor

i'm trying to move from imperative try-with-resources to reactive try-with-resources without success. I have the following piece of code i would like to move.

```
    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    private final String bucket;
  
    @Override
    public Mono<String> getTemplate(String templateId) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            S3Object s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(bucket, templateId);
            try (s3Object) {
                return IOUtils.toString(s3Object.getObjectContent());
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
```

I would like to rewrite using reactive try-with-resources construct.
My first try was using Flux.using

```
Flux.using(amazonS3.getObject(bucket, templateId),
                s3Object -> Flux.just(IOUtils.toString(s3Object.getObjectContent())),
                S3Object::close);
```

the s3Object is not being casted as an S3Object so getObjectContent doesn't exist.

Then i had a look athttps://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/ and i guess that i might use Disposable, however i'm not sure how to wrap S3Object with a disposable object.

Does anyone know how can i make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this with the approach you're taking. It's literally impossible to take a blocking API like the one you see here (AWS SDK v1) and somehow wrap it to make it reactive.

You can however use the AWS SDK v2 (you should be using this anyway for new development), which has an asynchronous S3 client ([`S3AsyncClient`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html)) that you can use to return a `CompleteableFuture<String>`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> contents = s3AsyncClient
    .getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().build(), new ByteArrayAsyncResponseTransformer<>())
    .thenApplyAsync(rb -> rb.asUtf8String());
```

You can then use `Mono.fromFuture(contents)` to obtain a `Mono<String>` from the above `CompleteableFuture`.

Comment: Well, according to https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking that might be possible.

Comment: You can wrap it in a reactive *type* and execute it on a backed threadpool (which is what happens in that link there - that's what the `boundedElastic` scheduler is doing.) This can *interface* blocking code like the above with a reactive chain, but it should very much be a method of last resort. Whatever you do, you can't make the blocking call itself reactive (i.e. executing asynchronously as part of an event loop.)

Comment: Great, i get your point now. So i ll try to move to AWS SDK v2 which is already async and use Mono.fromFuture to move to reactive types. Not sure if spring aws supports aws sdk v2 yet, but i'll have a look at it. Thx.

Comment: As far as I know they started the development on that but I don't think it'll be released in the near future.